# Using Xamarin.Forms in an originally non-Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have inherited maintenance and development over an app that was **originally written without Xamarin.Forms**, doing the UI layer for Android and iOS the traditional way with platform specific projects and a shared project for my business logic.

Given that most of the app screens are rather simple and I spend a disproportionate amount of time wrangling with platform specific UI code, I wanted to ask if anybody has **experience with integrating Xamarin.Forms** in a project that did not originally use Xamarin.Forms.

I was wondering if it was possible to **replace specific screens with Xamarin.Forms**, perhaps by hosting them manually inside the specific Android Activity or iOS Screen.

I would like to start out by integrating the next feature screen as a shared Xamarin.Forms "page".

Has anybody ever done anything like this before?

Comment: Interesting question.  I have recently done the opposite, recreated all of the simple screens of a non-forms app in forms and attached the more complex ones as custom renderers.  Is that an option for you?

Comment: A total refactoring isn't an option at the moment, however a rolling refactoring is. Which is why I'd like to implement simple new additions in XF instead of native. We're speaking of a listview-with-a-searchbox-and-button kind of simple.The screens don't really interact with one another in any complex way.

Answer (score 2):

We have done this due a redesign of the app. We have developed the app with MvvmCross and native UI and moved to Xamarin.Forms. We **threw away all views**, but kept the ViewModels. That means: If the UI layer is decoupled from your ViewModel layer (using data binding), it should be easy to switch completely.

I would not recommend, mixing up Forms and native Activities/ViewControllers, because handling the navigation properly, can be a pain (especially under android). If there is something complex on one screen, you should move this in a custom element with a custom renderer.

For mixing up there are two minimalist examples:

- https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Forms2Native
- https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Native2Forms

Comment: Sadly the app is as far from a proper MVC/MVVM implementation as spaghetti code can take it. In my case, the main app is really only a hub that calls other activities that do little to no interaction with the rest of the app. And absolutely none of it is complex, which is why XF would be a prime candidate.

Comment: Then have a look at the linked examples. If your Pages are really independent, then it might work.